# New in Firefox: Content Blocking notification

Tags: firefox

How to disable the *"New in Firefox Content Blocking"* popup in Firefox 68.0.1?

[image: content blocking]

Comment: Do you mean that once dismissed, it keeps on coming back?

Comment: @harrymc Prevent it from appearing in the first place.

Comment: That would be difficult.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your `user.js`/`about:config`, set `browser.contentblocking.introCount` to 20.
Source: https://support.mozilla.org/en-US/questions/1239183#answer-1169294